# Swift TableView not showing anything from the nib

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

my issue is that in Xcode 6.1 I think I have set up a custom cell correctly, but the simulator shows nothing just an empty table view, I'm not sure where is the mistake coming from. Any help?[image: Xcode view] 
[image: xcode view]

Comment: Try taking out the registerClass line. You shouldn't register both a class, and a nib. If the cell was made in a xib file, then only register the nib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing the tableView.datasource = self, got it.

Comment: You should still remove the line mentioned by rdelmar. It is unnecessary.